# Android Volley: How to check network data consumption of a request

Tags: android, android-volley, consumption

is there a way to programmatically measure how much network data is consumed by an Android Volley request?
In my specific case, I have an app that must perform some checks every 2 minutes by making Volley requests to the server, but I need to know if this is too expensive in terms of network data consumed.

Thanks!

Comment: one way is to use stetho with volley.

Comment: @SarthakMittal Thanks, I didn't know it, it's very useful!

Comment: good to know! although retrofit is much more advanced library for networking.